# Running 2 inserts in one transaction is executing unacceptably long time. Running same DML Separately works fine

Tags: postgresql, transaction

Decided to see what DBAs have to say about this because developers have no idea. I need to execute 2 DMLs in one transaction. First DML takes records from `Table1`, changes some values and inserts back into the same table a subset of the originals. Second DML selects the newly inserted records, joins them with the original records that were used to generate the subset, and inserts some values into `table2`

When I ran this from c# code under one transaction, first statement executed fine and then second kept going forever. So, I decided to check directly in the DB. - same thing.

Using Postgre SQL, if I run the block below, it just keeps running but not completing.. for hours. But the execution shows as `active`

If I Run these 2 statement separately, in separate transactions - takes few seconds.
What do I miss here? I am not very experienced with Postgres.

BTW, if I add `SELECT` after first statement and just run `INSERT` and `SELECT` under transaction, `select` runs fine and then if there is no `commit`, records are gone, as expected. It is running that second `INSERT` in the same transaction that is troublesome.
Thanks

```sql
begin;
INSERT INTO table1
    (fields...)  
SELECT <some fields and couple hard-coded values>
FROM table1
WHERE 
  <few conditions>
GROUP BY 
  <same fields as SELECT>;

INSERT INTO table2 (f1, f2) -- INSERT SUBSET based on uncommitted data from ^^^
select c.id, a.id
FROM 
   table1 t1 Inner JOIN -- SELF JOIN
   table1 t2 a On <condition> --(uuid, int, int)
where 
    <where conditions>;

COMMIT;
```

**-- Explain plan**

```
Insert on table2  (cost=220982.08..222767.83 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=1497.900..1497.902 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=220982.08..222767.83 rows=28181 width=40) (actual time=770.711..986.875 rows=94731 loops=1)
        ->  Merge Join  (cost=220982.08..222415.56 rows=28181 width=70) (actual time=770.635..934.304 rows=94731 loops=1)
              Merge Cond: (((a.someid)::text = (c.someid)::text) AND ((a.type)::text = (c.type)::text))
              ->  Sort  (cost=127241.69..127555.13 rows=125375 width=46) (actual time=673.203..737.628 rows=94731 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: a.someid, a.type
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 5208kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on table1 a  (cost=0.00..112768.01 rows=125375 width=46) (actual time=0.006..258.759 rows=94731 loops=1)
                          Filter: ((MustDoSome IS TRUE) AND (batchnumber = '2b86d81c-d76a-4184-b04f-6bdbeb78b51b'::uuid) AND (keytype = 1) AND (datarecordtype = 2))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 588905
              ->  Sort  (cost=93740.39..93787.02 rows=18650 width=46) (actual time=97.419..112.265 rows=94731 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: c.someid, c.type
                    Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 3448kB
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on statementdata c  (cost=727.30..92417.46 rows=18650 width=46) (actual time=8.072..44.686 rows=58677 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: (stmtkeytype = 2)
                          Filter: ((batchnumber = '2b86d81c-d76a-4184-b04f-6bdbeb78b51b'::uuid) AND (datarecordtype = 2))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 58677
                          Heap Blocks: exact=16204
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fki_fk_table1_stmt_key_type  (cost=0.00..722.63 rows=58428 width=0) (actual time=5.263..5.263 rows=117354 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (stmtkeytype = 2)
Planning Time: 0.557 ms
Trigger for constraint fk_xxx_zz_yyy_id: time=899.588 calls=94731
Trigger for constraint fk_xxx_yyy_id: time=837.080 calls=94731
Trigger for constraint fk_RRRR_yyyt_id: time=1001.268 calls=94731
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147648/discussion-on-question-by-t-s-running-2-inserts-in-one-transaction-is-executing); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an optimization, postgresql can skip checking foreign keys in some cases, but only if it's the first command in a transaction (i.e. previous commands in a transaction certainly couldn't affect the associated data). Unfortunately, I did not immediately find a check for the conditions of this optimization in the database code.

`Trigger for constraint fk_xxx_zz_yyy_id` - this is exactly the call of the foreign key check system trigger.

Comment: how does this apply to my case if have it - 2nd statement ?